# Unable to see JavaScript cookie in Developer tools or under cookie object

Tags: javascript, cookies, https

I'm very new to Javascript and I'm trying to create some cookies. I do not seem to be able to save them under document.cookie object for some reason. The main goal is to have a user write something in an  text field and upon clicking a button it saves that input in a cookie and in js use document.getElementById("elementID").value; to get the value of the user input. I've tried to create a cookie manually like document.cookie = "name=samu"; but it also does not show. After googling this exact task I found the following [page](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Document/Cookie/Read_value_from_a_input_text_field_and_use_it_as_cookie_value_in_JavaScript.htm) which had no problem creating a cookie from a user input in a text field. When checking under the developer tools > Application > Cookies I could see the cookie appear but I've even copy pasted the code and it did not work.
I followed the W3school example on how to set and create one but also did not work.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheet1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="objectosPredef.js"></script>
    <title>Actividad 2</title>
</head>
<body onload="listaPropiedades()">
    <div id="listaPropiedades"></div>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="entra tu nombre" />
    <button onclick="crearCookie();">Click</button>

</body>

</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function setCookie(nombre, valor, exp) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + exp * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var exp = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = nombre + "=" + valor + ";" + exp + ";path=/";
    alert(document.cookie);
}

function crearCookie() {
    var nombre = "nombre_usuario";
    var valor = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    alert(valor);
    var exp = 500;
    setCookie(nombre, valor, exp);
    
}
```

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cookies are ONLY set if you load your page from an http server - if you load your page from harddisk then you will not get cookies

Answer (score 0):

@mplungjan was right. I've downloaded Xampp and was able to save cookies and see them via the browser! thanks